# Get a Firebase Database Reference depending on a specific parameter - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I usually get the reference of my tupla from firebase database like this:

```
private DatabaseReference needsRef;

public void onCreate(...) {
     ...
     needsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("favors");
}
```

But now I would like to put inside "needsRef" just the rows which content a specify parameter call "type". If (type == "need"), put these rows in "needsRef" and if (type == "offer"), put it in another DatabaseReference called "offersRef".

[image: I show a screenshot of my database to clarify the question]

The child after "favors" on the database is a name which is not always the same. 
[image: I show the image]

Could u help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want two queries: one that contains just the needs, and another that contains just the offers. That is easily done with:

```
private Query needsQuery;
private Query offersQuery;

public void onCreate(...) {
     ...
     DatabaseReference favorsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("favors");
     needsQuery = favorsRef.orderByChild("type").equalTo("need");
     offersQuery = favorsRef.orderByChild("type").equalTo("offer");
}
```

The `Query` class I use here is a parent class of `DatabaseReference`, so it has many of the methods you already know from working with database references, and can be used in much the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an event Listener to you code (ie. A value event listener), you can create a for loop to loop through the Children. In this loop you then test using if statements based on type.

```
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            DataSnapshot needRef = dataSnapshot.child("favors");
            for (DataSnapshot snap : needRef.getChildren())
            {
                String type = snap.child("type").getValue().toString();

                //This then references the type you need. Just add children as you need to get to the needed node
                dataSnapshot.child(type)...;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check value like below code :

```
   ArrayList<DataClass> temp1 = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<DataClass> temp2 = new ArrayList<>();
   @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        if(!temp1.isEmpty() && !temp2.isEmpty())
           temp1.clear();temp2.clear();         

        DataSnapshot dataSnapTemp = dataSnapshot.child("favors");
        for (DataSnapshot datasnap : dataSnapTemp.getChildren())
        {
            String type = datasnap.child("type").getValue().toString();
            if(type.equals("need")){
                temp1.add(your object)
            }else if(type.equals("need")){
                temp2.add(your object)
            }
        }
    }
```